# Imputation with mice - exclude variable from being imputed but still use as predictor

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, multi-level, r-mice

So I tried to impute some missing data and there is a problem. I want three variables to be used as **predictors** but I *don't* want them to **be imputed**. Even though I specified the predictormatrix as the following:

```
# Initialize
m0 = mice(datimp, maxit = 0)

predmat = m0$predictorMatrix
m0$predictorMatrix
m0$method

meth = m0$method
meth["cm.dep.0"] = "2l.pan"
meth["cm.dep.1"] = "2l.pan"
meth["cm.dep.2"] = "2l.pan"


# Group is added as a fixed effect to all variables
predmat[,"trial"] = -2
predmat[,"group"] = 1
predmat["sess",]= 0
predmat["depmed",]= 0
predmat["prevpsychoth",]= 0
predmat

             trial group sex age sess degree rel child depmed prevpsychoth cm.dep.0 cm.dep.1
trial           -2     1   1   1    1      1   1     1      1            1        1        1
group           -2     1   1   1    1      1   1     1      1            1        1        1
sex             -2     1   0   1    1      1   1     1      1            1        1        1
age             -2     1   1   0    1      1   1     1      1            1        1        1
sess             0     0   0   0    0      0   0     0      0            0        0        0
degree          -2     1   1   1    1      0   1     1      1            1        1        1
rel             -2     1   1   1    1      1   0     1      1            1        1        1
child           -2     1   1   1    1      1   1     0      1            1        1        1
depmed           0     0   0   0    0      0   0     0      0            0        0        0
prevpsychoth     0     0   0   0    0      0   0     0      0            0        0        0
cm.dep.0        -2     1   1   1    1      1   1     1      1            1        0        1
cm.dep.1        -2     1   1   1    1      1   1     1      1            1        1        0
cm.dep.2        -2     1   1   1    1      1   1     1      1            1        1        1
             cm.dep.2
trial               1
group               1
sex                 1
age                 1
sess                0
degree              1
rel                 1
child               1
depmed              0
prevpsychoth        0
cm.dep.0            1
cm.dep.1            1
cm.dep.2            0
```

In the end `sess`, `depmed` and `prevpsychoth` are being imputed. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the column rather than the row to zero as well as emptying the method of not-to-be-imputed variables should work. *Example with `nhanes` data set from `mice`*

```
library(mice)
m0 <- mice(nhanes, maxit=0)

meth <- m0$method
meth[names(meth) %in% c("bmi")] <- ""
pred <- m0$predictorMatrix
pred[, colnames(pred) %in% c("bmi")] <- 0   

imp <- mice(nhanes, predictorMatrix=pred, method=meth)
imp$imp
complete(imp, "long")[1:25, ]

imp <- mice(nhanes, predictorMatrix=pred, method=m0$method)
```

### Result

```
complete(imp, "long")[1:25, ]
#    .imp .id age  bmi hyp chl
# 1     1   1   1   NA   1 238
# 2     1   2   2 22.7   1 187
# 3     1   3   1   NA   1 187
# 4     1   4   3   NA   1 206
# 5     1   5   1 20.4   1 113
# 6     1   6   3   NA   1 184
# 7     1   7   1 22.5   1 118
# 8     1   8   1 30.1   1 187
# 9     1   9   2 22.0   1 238
# 10    1  10   2   NA   1 186
# 11    1  11   1   NA   1 238
# 12    1  12   2   NA   1 186
# 13    1  13   3 21.7   1 206
# 14    1  14   2 28.7   2 204
# 15    1  15   1 29.6   1 238
# 16    1  16   1   NA   1 238
# 17    1  17   3 27.2   2 284
# 18    1  18   2 26.3   2 199
# 19    1  19   1 35.3   1 218
# 20    1  20   3 25.5   2 199
# 21    1  21   1   NA   1 187
# 22    1  22   1 33.2   1 229
# 23    1  23   1 27.5   1 131
# 24    1  24   3 24.9   1 186
# 25    1  25   2 27.4   1 186
```

Comment: your answer was accepted, @jay.sf, but from what I understand from it, `BMI`  was not used as a predictor (and @Lea pretended the three variables she mentioned to be used as predictors). am I right? I would like the same as Lea, but [this issue](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/321) suggests that, in fact, it would not be possible.

Comment: @MDSF You seem to be right, thanks for pointing that out. At least the BMI is not imputed.

Comment: @MDSF Maybe we can just `cbind` unimputed BMI to the `complete` result: `cbind(complete(imp, "long"), rep(nhanes$bmi, imp$m))`, without setting BMI predictor column to zero of course and thus using BMI as predictor.

Comment: Setting the column to 0 excludes the variable as _predictor_, it does not exclude it from the set of variables to be imputed. See van Buuren's `mice` book [here](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-modelform.html), section _6.3.2 Predictors_: "A value of 1 indicates that the column variable is a predictor to impute the target (row) variable, and a 0 means that it is not used."